# Trigger timer trigger Azure function from powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-functions, azure-powershell

I am implementing an automation script (Powershell) for integration and performance testing where I need to trigger timer based azure function. Is there a way to trigger function from Powershell ?

Answer (score -1):

- Timer Trigger function is a non Http-Triggered Function & lets you
  run a function on a schedule based on the CORN Expression.
- You could trigger it on-demand via the Admin APIs as shown in the
  [below doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-manually-run-non-http)

Using the below  script you can trigger the HTTP functions from the remote PowerShell

```
$YourURI = 'FunctionUrl'
 Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri "$($YourURI)&name=<username>!"
```

Here is the sample response for the above script
[image]